# scrapy duplicate filter with csv file

Tags: csv, duplicates, scrapy

Im trying to avoid scraping the same information more than once, i run this spider every morning to scrape jobs from a job board, then i copy them into excel and press the remove duplicates from the list using URL. i would like to do this in scrapy (i can change the txt file to csv). i would be happy to implement middleware to

this is the pipleing that i am trying to use

```
class CraigslistSamplePipeline(object):



    def find_row_by_id(item):
        with open('URLlog.txt', 'r') as f:                # open my txt file with urls from previous scrapes
            urlx = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()] # extract each url
            if urlx == item ["website_url"]:              # compare old url to URL being scraped
            raise DropItem('Item already in db')      # skip record if in url list
        return
```

im sure this code is wrong, can someone please suggest how i can do this, Im very new to this so explaining each line would help me alot. i hope my question makes sense and someone can help me

ive looked at these posts for help, but was not able to solve my problem:

[How to Filter from CSV file using Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530301/how-to-filter-from-csv-file-using-python-script)

[Scrapy - Spider crawls duplicate urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104831/scrapy-spider-crawls-duplicate-urls)

[how to filter duplicate requests based on url in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553117/how-to-filter-duplicate-requests-based-on-url-in-scrapy)

Comment: Are you saying that 'urlx' winds up containing duplicates after it is read from the file?

Comment: no, this code doesn't work, i don't write to urlx at all, urlx just gets it from the URLlog.txt file, and i add urls to URLlog.txt manually after the scrape is finished

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `in` keyword. Like so:

```
 if item['website_url'] in urlx:
      raise DropItem('Item already in db')
```

You loaded `urlx` from a file where each line is a url. It is now a list. The `in` keyword checks to see if the website url is in the list `urlx`. If it is, it returns true. Keep in mind the comparison is case sensitive in my example. You may want to call `.lower()` on the website url and on the urls loaded from the file.

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but I assume you just want something that works.

Comment: thanks Eric, im so excited to get this to work. if you know of more efficient ways to do this i would love to hear, this whole scrapy project has been me copying and pasting snipets of code from the internet so my knowledge of best practice and most efficient ways to do things is very limited