# How to force scrapy to crawl duplicate url?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am learning [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) a web crawling framework.
by default it does not crawl duplicate urls or urls which scrapy have already crawled.

How to make Scrapy to crawl duplicate urls or urls which have already crawled?
I tried to find out on internet but could not find relevant help.

I found `DUPEFILTER_CLASS = RFPDupeFilter` and `SgmlLinkExtractor` from [Scrapy - Spider crawls duplicate urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104831/scrapy-spider-crawls-duplicate-urls) but this question is opposite of what I am looking

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `dont_filter=True` argument on `Request()`.
See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

Comment: But this would also disable other filters such as offsite

Answer (score 32):

A more elegant solution is to disable the duplicate filter altogether:

```
# settings.py
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'
```

This way you don't have to clutter all your Request creation code with `dont_filter=True`. Another side effect: this only disables duplicate filtering and not any other filters like offsite filtering.

If you want to use this setting selectively for only one or some of multiple spiders in your project, you can set it via [`custom_settings`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) in the spider implementation:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }
```

Comment: It depends, I may have more than one spider sharing the same general settings.

Comment: Yes, in this case you better use custom_settings instead of settings.py. Adjusted the answer to reflect this.